# why 1st code is executed but 2nd gives the CloneNotSupportedException

Tags: java

```
class test   {
    public    static void main(String as[]){
       Hello h=new Hello();
       Object obj=h.clone();
       System.out.println(obj==h);
    }
}
class Hello{
    protected Object clone(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

it is working without implementing interface

But this code:

```
class test23 {
    public static void main(String as[]) throws Exception {
        Hello23 h1 = new Hello23(99);
        Object h2 = h1.clone();
        System.out.println(h1 == h2);
    }
}

class Hello23 {
    int a;

    Hello23(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }
}
```

is throwing an `CloneNotSupportedException`?

Answer (score 3):

You may *think* your code is working, but as a matter of fact, it is not.

It doesn't actually create a clone of your object. It's a simple method that just happens to be called `clone()`, which returns a reference to the same object.

If it was actually cloning the object, then you should have gotten `false` from your comparison, because a clone is a new, separate object and so a reference to it would be different than the reference to the original object.

So, for a method that just happens to be called `clone` but could also have been called `giveMeAReference`, there is no issue with the `Cloneable` interface. It just calls the method and returns the result. A result which is *not* a clone of the object and therefore does not fulfill the `Cloneable` and `clone()` contract.

But what would happen if your `clone` method calls `super.clone()`?

The superclass is `Object`. Object has a `clone()` method which is reachable from its subclasses. But what this method does is first check if the current object implements the `Cloneable` interface.

Since your class doesn't, the `CloneNotSupportedException` exception is thrown by `Object.clone()`. If your class declared itself `implements Cloneable`, then the check would have passed in `Object.clone()` so `super.clone()` would have returned a native clone of your actual object, and no exception would have been thrown.

The key here is that if you are not actually calling `super.clone()` you are not actually going through the cloning mechanism, and you method is just a plain method that violates the `clone()` contract.

Answer (score 0):

When `Hello` call `clone` method, it returns this object's *reference*, and when use `==` to compare objects, it will compare whether the *reference* is equal. for your `clone` method just return the reference of `Hello` object, so they should be equal.

For `Cloneable` class, it doesn't contain the `clone` method, it just indicates this class can be cloned(field one by one), so you must Override `clone` method in your class.

Comment: without implementing Cloneable interface how does it work class test23{
public static void main(String as[])throws Exception{
 Hello23 h1=new Hello23(99);
 Object h2=h1.clone();
 System.out.println(h1==h2);
}
}
class Hello23{
 int a;
 Hello23(int a){
  this.a=a;
 }
 protected Object clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{
  return super.clone();
 }
}it raises CloneNotSupported Exception

Comment: @SUDHANSHUSHEKHAR Do not put any code in comments. If you want to add information, add it in your question with a title like "Edit, I have this additional information:", **format it properly**, and then write a comment where appropriate saying "I have added an edit to my question". Comments are not the place for code.